# How to bind events using addEventListener in angular 2 single page application

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener

I have a js library which will add events to all form fields. It works fine when I add this library to multi-page application. But in case of single page application, it works only on DOM elements which are loaded initially. Since my angular 2 application updates the DOM/view I can not able to add events to newly added DOM element.

Is there any way to add event listeners to newly added DOM elements?